# Sinatra settings - variables nested in environment not working? (Sinatra::ConfigFile)

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a modular Sinatra app using [Sinatra::ConfigFile](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/config_file.html) and have broken out my settings into a yaml file so I can modify paths/urls when in different environments.

As a basic example, I have:

```
development:
  url_root: 'http://127.0.0.1:9292'

production:
  url_root: 'http://domain.com'
```

However, `settings.url_root` does not work (undefined method 'url_root') unless I pull it out of the nested environment block. Checking my environment: `p ENV['RACK_ENV']` returns `development`.

I am using Sinatra 1.4.5, sinatra-contrib 1.4.2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This works as expected for me (with both ways of laying out the config file). There must be something else going on.

Answer (score 2):

OK, well it turns out it was a misunderstanding of, what I believe, is a slightly confusingly worded documentation on the Sintara page which states:

> But it also can provide specific environment configuration. There are
>   two ways to do that: at the file level and at the setting level. They
>   are illustrated, repsectively, as follows:

```
development:
  foo: development
  bar: bar
test:
  foo: test
  bar: bar
production:
  foo: production
  bar: bar
```

> and

```
 foo:
   development: development
   test: test
   production: production
   bar: bar
```

So, when using a settings yaml file with Sinatra, **you want to define the variable name and then nest the environments within it** (*not the other way around*), and the working format for my question above is:

```
url_root:
  development: 'http://127.0.0.1:9292'
  production: 'http://domain.com'
```

Comment: The documentation is a bit confusing I find too. I don't see the difference between `at file level` and `at settings level` and why the firs way of doing this doesn't work.